# Not able to add a list for a particular key in a dictionary in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#

There are two methods. GetSpecialityList and GetDoctorSpecialityList. The GetSpecialityList is fetching the specialityId corresponding to the specialityName in the form of key value pair.I am using this key value pair in the method GetDoctorSpecialityList to get the doctor list specific to the speciality name.
The GetSpecialityList is giving me the right mapping. But the GetDoctorSpecialityList is returning the set of all doctors corresponding to each speciality name.Can someone help me out with the solution?

Here is my code.
Model class:-

```
 public class DoctorInfo
 {
    [Key]
    public int doctorId { get; set; }
    public string dname { get; set; }
    public int specialityId { get; set; }
  }


  public class SpecialityInfo
  {
    [Key]
    public int specialityId { get; set; }
    public string specialityName { get; set; }
  }
```

Service class:-

```
       //To get the Speciality Id and the corresponding Speciality Name
    public Dictionary<Int32, string> GetSpecialityList()
    {
        conn.GetConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.GetCommand(Queries.GetSpeciality);
        List<Int32> list = new List<Int32>();
        Dictionary<Int32, string> SpecialityIdNameMap = new Dictionary<Int32, string>();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = null;
        mySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            SpecialityInfo specialityInfo = new SpecialityInfo();
            specialityInfo.specialityId = mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            specialityInfo.specialityName = mySqlDataReader.GetString(1);
            SpecialityIdNameMap.Add(specialityInfo.specialityId, specialityInfo.specialityName);
        }
        mySqlDataReader.Close();
        //conn.CloseConnection();
        return SpecialityIdNameMap;
    }

    //To get the list of doctors for a given speciality
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetDoctorSpecialityList()
    {
        conn.GetConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.GetCommand(Queries.GetDoctorNameForSpeciality);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> SpecialityDoctorMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        Dictionary<Int32, string> SpecialityIdNameMap = GetSpecialityList();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32, string> pair in SpecialityIdNameMap)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specialId", Convert.ToInt32(pair.Key));
            MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = null;
            mySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                DoctorInfo doctorInfo = new DoctorInfo();
                doctorInfo.dname = mySqlDataReader.GetString(1);
                list.Add(doctorInfo.dname);    
            }
            SpecialityDoctorMap.Add(pair.Value, list);
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            mySqlDataReader.Close();
        }
        conn.CloseConnection();
        return SpecialityDoctorMap;
    }
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the difference between your expected results and your actual results. Could you include some sample data of input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: (Also note that `Convert.ToInt32(pair.Key)` is unnecessary when `pair.Key` is already an `int`.)

Comment: Every specialityId has a particular specialityName. And every particular speciality name has a particular list of doctors specific to that specialityName. But , my GetDoctorSpecialityList is returning the list of all the that are present in the doctor table and not the doctors specific to a speciality name.The query is correct but there is a problem in the implementation of GetDoctorSpecialityList. The method is returning the all the doctor names for every specialityName and not the doctor Names for the specific specialityName.I want the doctor Names for the specific speciality name.

Comment: As I said before, all of that would be easier to understand with sample data instead of just a description.

Comment: Also, I strongly suspect that the SQL you're using is relevant, but you haven't shown us that - what's the value of `Queries.GetDoctorNameForSpeciality`?

Comment: Put `list = new List<string>();` inside foreach loop

Comment: Thank you Mam ,thanks a lot. The last suggestion worked. Thanks a lot indeed..